# Login to windows (10,11) machine with our own domain email

Tags: windows, azure-activedirectory

When we try to login to a new Windows computer (Windows 10 & 11) using our Office365 user, with our own domain email (user@ourdomain.com) we get the following error:

> Looks like this isn't a Microsoft account. Try another email or sign up for a new one.

When we try to create a new account we get the following error:

> You can't sign up here with a work or school email address. Use a personal email, such as Gmail or Yahoo!, or get a new Outlook email.

We opened a few support tickets at Microsoft, but nobody could find a solution yet.

Anyone know how we can achieve that?

Comment: Isn't it Windows Home edition? The messages would make sense if it was.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - The Azure AD tag suggests this cannot be Windows 10 Home.  However, I don't have high hopes, that the tag wasn't used properly.